# Как сделать так, чтобы сайдбар в WP видел шорткод с параметрами?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, sidebar

Как сделать так, чтобы сайдбар в WP видел шорткод с параметрами?

```
add_filter('widget_custom_html_content', 'do_shortcode');
add_shortcode('portfolio_photo', 'portfolio_photo'); 

  function portfolio_photo($attrs) {
    $params = shortcode_atts(array(
      'name' => 'me'
    ), $attrs);
    $name = $params['name']; 
    
    $str = get_template_directory_uri();
    $str_uri = $str . "/assets/img/{$name}.jpg";
    return $str_uri;
  }
```

Вывожу в сайдбаре
`<img src=[portfolio_photo name="photo"]  alt="My photo">`

Сайдбар выводит ошибку:

> Special characters must be escaped.

Предполагаю, что ошибка в экранировании, но не смог исправить. Буду рад за помощью.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Тег img нужно выводить внутри шорткода.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/530972)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Автор ответа и вопроса, одно лицо.

Comment: @0xdb и че??? ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor Будте внимательней. Оставайтесь вежливым.